# jQuery to run a function after Load More button click to style calendar events

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have been working on a Wordpress calendar to style the events titles, but ran into a small problem. When the user clicks the load more button the additional events are not styled.

My original code works for the page load but I was thinking of adding another function which executes once the button is pressed after a small delay.

I have tried to modify my original code to work with the button press and delay but I have been unable to get it to working.  Is there another way or is something missing in my code below.  Again all help is appreciated.

```
jQuery(function($){
    
$("mec-load-more-button").click(
    function() {
        console.log("clicked...waiting...");

        setTimeout(
            function() {
                
            $(".mec-bg-color ").each(function() {
  //use find to get text
    console.log($(this).find(".mec-event-loc-place").text());
    var text = $(this).find(".mec-event-loc-place").text().toLowerCase();
    var color = {
      'background-color': '#fff'
    };

    switch (text) {
      case "southern":
        color = "#ce1870";
        break;
      case "south eastern":
        color = "#00635b";
        break;
      case "belfast":
        color = "#7c318b";
        break;
       case "northern":
        color = "#b31212";
        break;
        case "western":
        color = "#ca9c05";
        break;
        
    }
    $(this).css("background-color", color);
               

            },
            2000);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be missing the "." on your click target (if mec-load-more-button is a class), Otherwise you are not targetting anything at all

```
$(".mec-load-more-button").click(...
```

if the first console log isn't working still, try to change the click event like this

```
$(".mec-load-more-button").on('click', function(e){ 
  ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks.  This fixed the issue but it seems to required the button to be pressed twice.  For example I click the button and it loads the additional unstyled events and then I need to click the button again and it styles them.